# How important are the rows vs columns in PCA?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, pca

So i have a dataset with pictures, where each column consist of a vector that can be reshaped into a 32x32 picture. The specific dimensions of my dataset is the following 1024 x 20000. Meaning 20000 samples of images.

Now when i look at various ways of doing PCA without using the built in functions from something like scikit-learn people tend to take either the mean of the rows and subtract the resulting matrix from the original one to get the covariance matrix. I.e the following

```
A = (1024x20000) #dimensions of the numpy array
mean_rows = A.mean(0)
new_A = A-mean_rows
```

Other times people tend to get the mean of the columns and the subtract that from the original matrix.

```
A = (1024x20000) #dimensions of the numpy array
mean_rows = A.mean(1)
new_A = A-mean_rows
```

Now my question is, when are you supposed to do what? Say i have a dataset as my example which of the methods would i use?

Looked at a variety of websites such as https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-principal-component-analysis-scratch-python/,
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about normalizing the dataset to have zero mean. You should compute the mean across the axis that contains each observation.

In your example, you have 20,000 observations with 1,024 dimensions each and your matrix has laid out each observation as a column so you should compute the mean of the columns.

In code that would be:
`A = A - A.mean(axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my inital try, but then when i proceed to calculate the covariance matrix as Cov(A) = np.dot(A^T, A), the dimensions does not fit anymore, meaning the resulting cov matrix is 20000x20000 when it should be 1024 as far as i understand.

Comment: You should compute the covariance as np.dot(A, A.T).

Comment: Your covariance matrix WILL be a 20k * 20k matrix as it is a co-variance between each pair of your 20k observations. So those are, infact, the correct dimensions that you need.